# OnBlur event without the ngModel & textfield blinking

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

Nativescript app: I am creating dinamy TextFields.

1) Probme - When i tap on dinamicly generated text field, the keyboard shows for miliseconds and the disapears. When i tap really fast a few times then the keyboard stays.

2) How to make onChange/onBlur event on dinamicly generated TextField? Like when i update the textField i need to call a method.

Here is the current list:
(blur) Does not work:
`<StackLayout col="1" row="0">
        <ListView [items]="categoryService.attributes | async">
          <template let-item="item" let-i="index">
            <GridLayout rows="50 100">
              <Label [text]="item.name"></Label>
              <TextField #input *ngIf="item.type=='text'" row="1" hint="Enter Value here" [text]="item.name" (blur)="categoryService.onAttributeChange(item, item.type, null, input.value)"></    TextField>
              <Switch #switch *ngIf="item.type=='checkbox'" row="1" checked="false" (checkedChange)="categoryService.onAttributeChange(item, item.type, null, switch.checked)"></Switch>
              <DropDown #aa
                *ngIf="item.type=='select'"
                row="1"
                [items]="categoryService.showAttributeValues(item.value)"
                [selectedIndex]="selectedIndex" 
                (selectedIndexChange)="categoryService.onAttributeChange(item, item.type, aa.selectedIndex)"></DropDown>
            </GridLayout>
          </template>
        </ListView>
      </StackLayout>`

Thanks!

Comment: HI IvRRimUm, The problem with the showing the keyboard for the `TextField` s in ListView has been already fixed and will be available in NS 2.4 - issue https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/2942

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About your second question you could use `textChange` method and to return `$event` as argument this will help you to get text for every `TextField` individually. You could review the sample code below. About the problem with showing the keyboard, it could be something related with the listview `itemTap` event. However this problem has been reproduced only on Android and still looking for possible solution.

app.component.html

```
<StackLayout>
    <ListView [items]="myItems" (itemTap)="onItemTap($event)">
        <template let-item="item" let-i="index" let-odd="odd" let-even="even">
            <StackLayout [class.odd]="odd" [class.even]="even">
                <Label [text]='"index: " + i'></Label>
                <Label [text]='"[" + item.id +"] " + item.name'></Label>
                <TextField (tap)="onTap($event)" hint="Enter text" text="" (textChange)="ontextChange($event)"></TextField>

            </StackLayout>
        </template>
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

app.component.ts

```
import {Component, Input, ChangeDetectionStrategy} from '@angular/core';
import {TextField} from "ui/text-field";
import app = require("application");

class DataItem {
    constructor(public id: number, public name: string) { }
}

@Component({
    selector: "my-app",
    templateUrl: "app.component.html",
})
export class AppComponent {
   public myItems: Array<DataItem>;
    private counter: number;
    public status =true;

    constructor() {
        this.myItems = [];
        this.counter = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            this.myItems.push(new DataItem(i, "data item " + i));
            this.counter = i;
        }
    }

    public onItemTap(args) {
        console.log("------------------------ ItemTapped: " + args.index);
    }

    public ontextChange(args){
        console.log("text "+args.object.text);
    }
}
```

I hope this helps